# Convert base 2 to base 10

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert base 2 to base 10, but I keep getting:

> "Value was either too large or too small for an Int64".

I use this code:

```
string number1 = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt64(numberBin1, 10));
```

It shows the error even with reasonable values, like: 000111110100111101010000

Edit: Fixed thanks to Johnny and JSteward

Comment: string number1 = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt64(numberBin1, 2));

Comment: The base parameter is `fromBase`, not `toBase`

Comment: What;s the type of  `numberBin1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter of the `ToInt64` method is `fromBase`, in your case it should be 2.

```
long number = Convert.ToInt64("000111110100111101010000", 2));
```